# How to tag a method / API as experimental?

Tags: c++

I'm developing a framework which has a class called `StableClass`.
This class is "stable": Users can rely their code on this class. Future versions of the framework will have this class, and it will be backwards compatible.

What I want is to add a method into this class, but I want to tell the users that this particular new methods is experimental, and might change in the future.

example:

```
class StableClass
{
public:
    void stableMethod1();
    void stableMethod2();
    void stableMethod3();
    void unstableMethod(); // How to tag this method as experimental ?
};
```

Users should know the `unstableMethod()` is experimental. That the API might change in the future (or not).

Possible options:

- add the `experimental` word as a suffix or prefix on the name. eg: `unstableMethod_experimental()`
- log to console every time the method is invoked
- tag it as deprecated, but in the warning says that it is experimental

Any other option ?

I would like to have the `experimental` attribute, and that the compiler raises a warning at compile time (like the `deprecated` attribute), but as far as I know, such attribute doesn't exist.

**[UPDATE]**:

I want to release a stable version of the framework, with a few APIs tagged as experimental. Sometimes it takes time to find the correct name, or the correct parameters or the correct functionality for a particular method, or implement it for all the supported platforms.

I want to tell my users that "this is the new stable version of the framework. We also added this new feature but it is experimental since it has the following limitations: ...".

So, I have this requirement where stable versions could have experimental features. Although it might sound like a contradiction, it is a requirement for me.

Comment: Not in the language standard. A compiler is at liberty to implement it as an extension, but in any case, I would recommend writing it down in the docs and not fiddling with the function name or any non-standard attributes.

Comment: Maybe: A single experimental function makes the entire library experimental (an experimental branch in the revision control)

Comment: This sounds like it should be a documentation thing, not a code thing...

Comment: @twYes, documentation is a valid option as well. If possible, I would like to make it more explicit.

Comment: @DieterLücking I updated the question. Tagging the whole version as an experimental, unfortunately, is not an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're on the right track. CSS does something similar with vendor-specific prefixes. For example:

```
.my-css-class {
    /* Border-radius for CSS3 compliant browsers */
    border-radius: 2px;

    /* Border-radius for browsers where CSS3 border-radius support
     * is experimental, or non-standard */
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
};
```

Because your method is experimental, it's reasonable to assume that the method may change significantly between now and the time you're happy with the API, and this comes with certain risks. Users of your "experimental" version of the API may have to implement hacks around your API to do what they want, and hopefully they'll report their problems to you, and allow you to better meet their needs.

By the time your method is finalized, your users' hacks may no longer be necessary, and worse, introduce bugs in *their code*, so it's desirable to force your API users to re-evaluate their code, and make sure that their code is correct before using the latest version of your API.

There are a multitude of ways you could do this gracefully, a couple I can think of:

## Rename your method

While your API is experimental, you could call your method something like this:

```
void EXPERIMENTAL_MyMethod();
```

Then later, you can remove the `EXPERIMENTAL_` prefix. When your users then choose update their own code to the latest API, they'll get a compiler error telling them that the experimental method is no longer available. This will force them to go through their own code and remove any hacks that were required when using the experimental version. At the very least, all they'll need to do is find/replace `EXPERIMENTAL_MyMethod()` with `MyMethod()`.

**PROS**:

- Simple, easy to work with.
- Obvious to see what is experimental and what is not.
- Greppable. Users can easily find `EXPERIMENTAL_` function calls in their code.

**CONS:**

- Makes experimental methods available within stable classes.
- Pollutes IDE auto-completion with unstable methods that the user might not want to use.

## Create a wrapper class

Like this:

```
namespace MyApi
{
    namespace Experimental
    {
       class StableClass;
    }

    class StableClass
    {
    public:
        void stableMethod1();
        void stableMethod2();
        void stableMethod3();

        friend class Experimental::StableClass;
    };    

    namespace Experimental
    {
        class StableClass : public MyApi::StableClass
        {
        public:
            void unstableMethod();
        };
    }
```

By using the "Experimental" namespace, like this...

```
MyApi::Experimental::StableClass myStableClassInstance;
```

... instead of this...

```
MyApi::StableClass myStableClassInstance;
```

... you're explicitly stating that anyone using the `Experimental` namespace versions of classes are subject to the whims of the developer. Once you've completed your stable version of the method, add it to the non-experimental version of the class, and remove `unstableMethod()` from the experimental version. Users of the `Experimental::MyClass` instance will then receive a compiler error. Your documentation can then explain what has changed.

**PROS:**

- Nice to look at, makes a clear distinction between the stable and unstable API.
- Makes it explicit what the user is getting into when they use the `Experimental` namespace.
- Forces users to re-evaluate their experimental API usage when breaking changes occur.

**CONS:**

- Requires work to maintain.
- Wrappers and additional namespaces could pollute your API.
- `using namespace Experimental;` *shudder*

Comment: This answer fits very well into our framework, since we are already using the `experimental` namespace for classes.

Comment: Although I haven't tested this solution yet, it seems that it won't work with subclasses. If the user already has a subclass of `StableClass`, and if he wants to use the new experimental feature, he will need to subclass from `experimental::StableClass` instead. Although it doesn't look like a major problem, I would prefer to force users to change existing code in order to use the new experimental feature.

Answer (score 6):

```
#ifdef EXPERIMENTAL
    void unstableMethod(); // How to tag this method as experimental ?
#endif
```

Hiding unreliable methods under appropriate defines will force users to alter their projects/targets preprocessor setting so they'll be aware of what they are dealing with.

Comment: Upvote. Make sure the defines default to hiding the methods, so users have to think about what they're asking for.

Comment: This may cause problems with the linker, I'd suggest using the `EXPERIMENTAL` to toggle between public/private.  Good idea though.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid option. But the issue with this approach is that it will enable all the experimental features, and a user might use an experimental feature without knowing it is experimental.  eg: User defines `EXPERIMENTAL` because he wants to use feature A, but it will also enable feature B. User might use Feature B (eg: IDE auto-completion) without knowing it is experimental.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in some of the comments, this needs to be handled outside of the source itself. Either via documentation or as a branch in your revision control system. When releasing the final stable version of the library you don't want to have to make people go through and change all the names in their code which is what would happen with an `_experimental` suffix.

Adding in compiler warning messages might be ok, but you may also irritate people who run with the "treat warnings as errors" option set.

Comment: *"When releasing the final stable version of the library you don't want to have to make people go through and change all the names in their code which is what would happen with an _experimental suffix."* This might actually be what is best. CSS, for example, does this with vendor prefixes (e.g. `-moz-border-radius`) because it indicates a property that might change it's behaviour prior to release. Similarly, adding an "_experimental" prefix or suffix will force API user's to re-evaluate their code and possibly remove any hacks once the final API implementation is completed.

Comment: @KarlNicoll Good analogy. Python has the `from __future__` which is not actually the same thing, but similar